# Really hard PDF question

Tags: probability

edit: I have just realised that this is a Gaussian (normal) distribution.. so i know how to find a pdf of gaussian distribution, but not sure how to apply that to this still, i am confused about the $X= \frac{y-4}{2}$ part.

$f_Y(y)=\frac{1}{2 \sqrt{2\pi}}e^{\frac{-(y-4)^{2}}{8}}$,$y \in\mathbb R$

a.) What is the PDF of the random variable $X=\frac{y-4}{2}$

b.)Find the p.d.f. and identify the distribution of the random variable $W=X^2$ and find $\gamma(\frac{1}{2})$

c.) Let $Z$ be a normal random variable, independent of $Y$ , with mean $1$ and variance
$25$. Find
$E(YZ - 4X^2 + 2)$ and $Var(2Y - 3Z + 2)$

I need to understand this type of question for an exam but am completely stuck as it is much harder than any in my books, i can usually do more basic pdf questions and EX and Var X questions so i have some basic knowledge of Probability and pdfs...

I havent put a detailed attempt as i really dont know what to do, apart from i know the pdf integral should equal one, but i dont know what to inetgrate in this situation.

Many thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

a) Note that for any invertible transformation $g$,

$$f_X(x) = \frac{ f_Y\bigl(g^{-1}(x)\bigr) }{ |g'\bigl(g^{-1}(x)\bigr)|},$$

where $g(y)=(y-4)/2$.  Can you do the rest?  (you should get a standard normal)

b) Use the fact that $f_{|X|}(x)=2f_X(x)$ for all $x>0$ and then use the displayed equation above.  You should get a $\chi_1^2$.  I don't know what you mean by $\gamma(1/2)$.

c) Note that $E(A+B)=EA+EB$ for any two random variables $A,B$ and that if they are independent also $E(AB)=EAEB$ and $V(A+B)=VA+VB$.

Hth

Answer (score 0):

A normal distribution with mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$ has a density of $\displaystyle \frac{1}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{\frac{-(y-\mu)^{2}}{2 \sigma^2}}$.  In your case $\mu=4$ and $\sigma^2=4$ so the standard deviation is $\sigma=2$.

If this is the the density of a random variable $Y$, then $X=\frac{Y-\mu}{\sigma}$ has what is called a standard normal distribution with mean $0$ and variance (and standard deviation) $1$. Its density is  $\displaystyle \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{\frac{-x^{2}}{2}}$

For (b) think about the [$\chi^2$ distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi-square_distribution)

For (c) think about the linearity of expectation and what happens to variances when a random variable is multiplied by a scalar or added to an independent random variable